# PyQt : relative widget size

Tags: qt, pyqt

I have a horizontal `QSplitter` and 2 widgets. By default, both widgets take up 50% of the available height.

I would like my top widget to take, say, 80% of the space. Any simple way to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
splitter.setStretchFactor(0, 1.6)
```

Note that you should call this method *after* the widgets being inserted in the `QSplitter`.

Comment: That should be 2 and and 8.

Comment: I liked your previous `setSizes` fix for cleverness, though.

Comment: Did you read the reference about this? Allthough i have to admitt that this is untested. `void QSplitter::setStretchFactor(int index, int stretch)` - *Updates the size policy of the widget at position index to have a stretch factor of stretch.

stretch is not the effective stretch factor; the effective stretch factor is calculated by taking the initial size of the widget and multiplying it with stretch*

Comment: I need more coffee. I was still thinking in terms of setting a list of values, not index and value. You are correct.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. Both my widgets still take up 50% of the height.

Comment: Can you try to use `sizes = splitter.sizes()` and then `splitter.setSizes([sizes[0] * 1.6, sizes[1] * 0.4])`? If that does not work you should provide code in your question. -- you should, of course, subsitute `splitter` with the name of your `QSplitter` instance

Comment: OK it actually worked, you should add in your answer - for future reference - that the `setStretchFactor()` method has to be called *after* the widgets have been inserted to the `QSplitter` ;). I will accept your answer